# AutoLisp function won't work with valid args in a file but works in another

Tags: types, arguments, autolisp

It's a function that takes 3 args (point list) and returns a vector. It works fine in other files but in not in the file I need (error "bad argument type: 2D/3D point: nil"). Points supplied to the function can be used well in a command function to draw a line which is OK. AutoCAD restarted.

Function:

```
(defun Bisect3p (Op, p1, p2 / V1 V2)
  (setq V1 (mapcar '- p1 Op)
    V2 (mapcar '- p2 Op)
  )  
  (GS:NORMALIZE (mapcar '+ (GS:NORMALIZE v1) (GS:NORMALIZE v2)))
)
```

and

```
(defun GS:Normalize (v)
  ((lambda (l)
     (if (/= 0 l)
       (mapcar (function (lambda (x) (/ x l))) v)
     )
   )
    (distance '(0 0 0) v)
  )
)
```

Data that works in one fie but not another even when points are acquired manually with `GETPOINT` but works like this:

```
(BISECT3P 
'(-0.575892 -1.27646 2.82506) 
'(-0.219971 -1.45442 2.69577) 
'(-0.219971 -1.05649 2.82506) 
)
```

not like this:

```
(Bisect3p ed_start ed_end a_start)
```

where args hold the same values
I would like to understand what is this.

Comment: You should remove the commas between each argument in the function definition.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe You have the same variable names in calling function and other function, so it overrides Your values one step before to `nil`.
So Your functions get nils.
To check that You can `(print Op)` and other input variables or run in debug mode to check which variable and where get `nil` passed.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the `OSNAPCOORD` variable from the default value of 2 to 1.

I suppose the object snap is set differently in each file.

Answer (score 0):

Lisp doesn't use comma's between the variables. Just spaces:

```
(defun Bisect3p (Op, p1, p2 / V1 V2)
```

Should be:

```
(defun Bisect3p (Op p1 p2 / V1 V2)
```

---

Ps. For getting a unit vector (gs:normalize) you can also use this function I wrote:

```
(defun Mat:unit (v)
  ;; Unit Vector - dexus
  ;; Args: v - vector
  (trans '(0 0 1) v 0 t)
)
```